# JNA Callback Performance too slow for streaming log. How can it be improved?

Tags: java, kotlin, jna

I have a simple JNA Callback that live-streams a log to me from a device one `char` at a time. In C, this function performs really well, and uses very little CPU resources. When I access it from JNA, it uses the entire CPU core it seems, and the log lags 5-20 seconds behind the live log.

I'm trying to find a more performant way to do the same thing, preferably with JNA, as it's convenient. I was reading that JNA's Direct Mapping can provide better performance, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is current the Callback. I don't actually use the `Pointer user_data`. I just casgt the byte to a `char`:

```
import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public interface syslog_relay_receive_cb_t extends Callback {
    void apply(byte c, Pointer user_data);
}
```

I'm feeding it into a JNA Library:

```
int syslog_relay_start_capture(syslog_relay_client_t client, syslog_relay_receive_cb_t callback, Pointer user_data);
```

Comment: In JDK 16 there were introduced new APIs ([Foreign Linker API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/389), [Foreign-Memory Access API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/393) to mitigate limitations and performance problems of JNI/JNA. They are still incubating, but probably worth experimenting with (here is a nice tutorial: https://blog.arkey.fr/2021/02/20/a-practical-look-at-jep-389-in-jdk16-with-libsodium/)

Comment: Take a look at the direct vs. indirect mappings of `qsort` in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cky/7397db4908fa9616539b)